# Image Processing: Determining a trapezoid from a list of points

Tags: image-processing

The problem is fairly simple: I have the following image.

[image]

My list of points is the white pixels, I have them stored in a texture. What would be the best and possibly most efficient method to determine the trapezoid they define? (Convex shape with 4 corners, doesn't necessarily have 90 degree angles).

The texture is fairly small (800x600) so going for CUDA/CL is definetly not worth it (I'd rather iterate over the pixels if possible).

Comment: What languages are ok? What tools are ok?

Comment: @Mark Setchell I'm using C / C++ / OpenGL currently, but that's not the problem. I'm planning to implement the algorithm myself without using any libraries so it's really just the algorithm I'm looking for...

Comment: The normal approach is the Hough Transform for detecting incomplete lines... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform You can try it out in Terminal with **ImageMagick** to see if it works for you without needing to write any code... https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25476

Comment: It's available in OpenCV too https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks! That definetly appears to be what I'm looking for :) One more question: can it detect the 4 sides of the shape in one pass, or do I need to re-run the algo. 4-times for each line?

Comment: It'll do all 4 in one go. Have a try and see how you get on - you can always come back and ask more as questions, and answers, are free! Someone may come up with something better so keep watching :-)

Comment: I wrote up an answer summarising the comments and adding some examples. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want, i.e. detect lines from incomplete information, using the [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform).

There is a cool demo of it in the examples accompanying [CImg](http://cimg.eu) which itself is a rather nice, simple, header-only C++ image processing library. I have made a video of it here, showing how the accumulator space on the right is updated as I move the mouse first along a horizontal bar of the cage and then down a vertical bar. You can see the votes cast in the accumulator and that the point in the accumulator gradually builds up to a peak of bright white:

[image]

---

You can also experiment with **ImageMagick** on the command-line without needing to write or compile any code, see example [here](https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25476). **ImageMagick** is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

So, using your image:

```
magick trapezoid.png -background black -fill red -hough-lines 9x9+10 result.png
```

[image]

Or, if you want the underlying information that identifies the 4 lines:

```
magick trapezoid.png -threshold 50% -hough-lines 9x9+10 mvg:

# Hough line transform: 9x9+10
viewbox 0 0 784 561
# x1,y1 x2,y2 # count angle distance
line 208.393,0 78.8759,561  # 14 13 312
line 0,101.078 784,267.722  # 28 102 460
line 0,355.907 784,551.38  # 14 104 722
line 680.493,0 550.976,561  # 12 13 772
```

If you look at the numbers immediately following the hash (`#`), i.e. 14, 28, 14, 12 they are the *votes* which correspond to the number of points/dots in your original image along that line. That's is why I set the `threshold` to 10, in the `9x9+10` part - rather than using the 40 in the **ImageMagick** example I linked to. I mean you have relatively few points on each line so you need a lower threshold.

---

Note that the Hough Transform is also available in other packages, such as [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html).

Comment: Thank you really much :) I implemented this yesterday with ~150 lines of C, works really well! I also parallelized / SIMD-d parts of the code and managed to process 100k points at 60fps!

Comment: Excellent - well done! You can always add your code as an answer, accept it and bag the points :-) Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely upload my method when fully finished, but I'll leave your answer as accepted since you actually helped me solve the problem :) I do have another question though: https://imgur.com/sZYPhqb This is my current result with your method. Do you know a fast way to determine the corners of the quad? My first thought was to take the derivative of the image, blur it, then get the corners but I'm pretty sure there's a faster way using the CPU...

Comment: PS. I could just compute the intersection point of the lines, but sometimes there may be multiple lines on a side...

Comment: Some tools that do Hough transform allow you to set a larger angle quantization. Others like imagemagick have some other arguments that help in that way.